# Put a tab autocompleted path into current buffer

Tags: autocompletion, filesystem

I use autocompletion a lot, especially for long path names:

e.g.

`$ /home/au/Doc<tab> <tab>uments/A<tab> <tab>\ file\ with\ a\ very\ long\ name`

This can be performed within vim:

`:!ls <full path - with tabbed autocompletion>`

**What is the best way to get a long and difficult to accurately type path into the current buffer?**

I was thinking along the lines of using the :!ls  one above, then going back to the start of the line and changing the `:!ls` bit to yank the text (I have no idea how to achieve this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last command executed is available in a register. Specifically, the `:` register. So autocomplete the path, submit the command and then in the buffer in Normal mode simply

```
":p
```

...to paste in the command and path. Edit away the non-path parts as needed.

For a bit more of an automated approach you can extract the filename before dumping it into the buffer.

Let's say my command was `:!ls /foo/bar/baz.txt`. Following that with...

```
:let @x = split(@:, " ")[-1]
```

(Assuming no spaces in your path!) This splits the output on spaces and takes the last element (`[-1]`) of  the resulting list (ie. the path) and stores it into register 'x' ... and we know that pasting the register's contents into the buffer is just a matter of `"xp`. (Basic registers are a familiar and easy way to get vim command output into a buffer. I mention one of various alternatives at the end of this post.)

Taking things way beyond minimums, you could even have Vim parse the path using the `fnamemodify()` function which takes a path and one or more modifiers that can do things like extract the head, file only, extension, all but extension, etc.

For example, after the `!ls` command do:

```
:let @x = fnamemodify(split(@:, " ")[-1], ":p:h")
```

Where the modifiers indicate "head" of "(full) path" That will save `/foo/bar` into register x and then, as before, insert it with `"xp`.

Vim can do all kinds of path/string processing. This is just a couple examples to introduce the idea. (Or you may just want to paste register `:` as is and be done with it.)

**Alternatives to register `:`**

Another quick way to get part of a previously executed command is to hit `q:` which will put you in Ex mode. There you can look at any command in history and cut/paste any bits you want to transfer to the buffer. Navigate in the window that is opened in this mode just like you navigate a normal buffer.

An interesting approach that never even crossed my mind is mentioned in a comment below by @D.Ben Knoble : from Insert mode enter a `/` (as in filesystem root) and trigger filename completion with `<c-x><c-f>`. A popup will show all top level dirs and files and you can select one with `<c-y>` then hit `<c-x><c-f>` again and choose another and so on. A little awkward for me personally versus a bunch of `<Tab>`s but clever enough to deserve a mention here. :)

**Path in command *output***

What if the command output rather than the command itself contains the  path (or anything else you want to extract). Here are a few things you can do.

- From Insert mode use the expression register to run a command. Output will be fed directly to the buffer. `:h @=`
- Use `:put =command(args)` to insert command output. (This is similar mechanism to that used in previous item.) `:h :put`
- Use redirection to store command output in a register or variable. (`:h :redi`)

Comment: Also Ctrl-x ctrl-f?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Just noticed this. OP's primary use case is leveraging command-line for auto-completion of, I believe, absolute paths (especially long ones). I thought ctrl-x ctrl-f just presents you with files in the cwd. What did you have in mind?

Comment: You can start with / :P just thought it might be worth a mention.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble LOL. Oh. Didn't think of that. Thanks. I'll play around with it when I get a minute.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Finally gave you your due. :D